# How to only insert if value is NOT NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I have a psql function that looks similar to the one below:

```
DO

$$

    DECLARE

    rec client;

    BEGIN
        FOR rec IN
        
        SELECT * FROM client
        
        LOOP

        INSERT INTO client_ethnic_identity

        (client_id, ethnic_identity_id)

        VALUES

        (rec.id, rec.ethnic_identity_id);

        END LOOP;
    END;

$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
```

I'd like to only have the `INSERT` run if the `ethnic_identity_id` on the `client` table has a value (i.e is not null).

Comment: Add a `WHERE` condition: `SELECT * FROM client WHERE ethnic_identity_id IS NOT NULL`. Also, don't use `*`. Select only the columns you need.

Comment: Hey @LaurenzAlbe thanks for chiming in but this doesnt seem to work. When i do `SELECT id, ethnic_identity_id FROM client WHERE ethnic_identity_id IS NOT null` I get `ERROR:  column "id" does not exist` in `RAISE NOTICE '%, %',  id,  ethnic_identity_id;`

Comment: The rest of your code should not change.

Answer (score 3):

You actually could phrase this as an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` and avoid the need for a function:

```sql
INSERT INTO client_ethnic_identity (client_id, ethnic_identity_id)
SELECT id, ethnic_identity_id
FROM client
WHERE ethnic_identity_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Way better than a stored procedure for sure.

Comment: Hello, I'm new to writing inserts from selects and have re-written your querty to what I believe looks right: `INSERT INTO 
client 
(id, ethnic_identity_id)
SELECT id, ethnic_identity_id FROM client WHERE ethnic_identity_id IS NOT NULL;` However this raises the following error: `ERROR:  null value in column "phone_number" of relation "client" violates not-null constraint`

Comment: That is due to `client` table declaring a column `phone_number ... not null` without a default value. As a result your `insert` statements **must** include a value for `phone_number`. Your insert fails to include that column's value, thus the exception. It has nothing to due with *insert select* vs. *insert values*.